# How to fill column as function of values of other vector

Tags: r, tidyverse

Imagine that you have two vector as

```
t <- c(1,2,3)
c <- c(0.9, 0.8, 0.4)
```

And you want to fill other vector with the correspondient values:

```
t2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
c2 <- c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4)
```

And you want to get (this is the question) "c2"
In other words, you have "t", "c" y "t2" and you want obtain "c2"

Is it possible to do, automatically ?
Thanks

Comment: Try `match`, e.g. `c[match(t2, t)]`.

Answer (score 2):

use `setNames`

```
unname(setNames(c, t)[as.character(t2)])
[1] 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.8 0.8 0.4
```